# Is there any difference between "is called the" vs. "is called a"?

Tags: differences, articles

Is there any difference between "is called the" vs. "is called a"?

Examples from [ISO/IEC 9899:2011 (E)](https://www.iso.org/standard/57853.html) (emphases added via **bold font**):

> The identifier immediately following the `define` is called **the** *macro name*.

> This pattern is called **the** *usual arithmetic conversions*:

> The least significant bit is called **the** *low-order bit*; the most significant bit is called **the** *high-order bit*.

> After preprocessing, a preprocessing translation unit is called **a** *translation unit*.

> Such a representation is called **a** trap representation.

> This construction is called **a** *cast*.

Comment: Is this any different from asking what the definite and indefinite articles mean in general? They don't have any special meaning here.

Comment: This has [been asked before](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93973/is-called-article) but none of the answers were particularly authoritative - perhaps reflecting the fact that in most cases it's just the standard rule for articles, and in other cases it doesn't matter. (However, standards documents often use language in specific or non-standard ways, so it might be slightly different in this case.)

Comment: I think we'd need the full context (non-paywalled) to know exactly why the indefinite and definite articles were used in these sentences. But I think this is just a result of the usual rules for when each article is used.

Comment: A is for General and The is for specific. You can't go wrong with that.

Comment: There aren't any authoritative answers. Language is full of options that can't be dealt with authoritatively.

Answer (score 0):

The definite article "the" can imply that something is unique. The word *unique* means that there is only one of something. The word *unique* comes from the Latin word unicus, which is a contraction of unus + -icus.

For example, imagine someone says, "Please give me a towel." The speaker is asking for any towel, not a specific one. But if the speaker says, "Please give me the towel," the speaker is referring to a specific towel.

Let's look at one of your examples.

> The least significant bit is called the low-order bit; the most significant bit is called the high-order bit.

In this sentence, the definite article plays an important role. The word "the" implies that there is only one low-order bit, and only one high-order bit.

This happens to be the case. Let's look at an example of a byte.

`1000 0000`

In the byte shown above, the high-order bit is 1 and the low-order bit is 0. There is only one high-order bit, and only one low-order bit. In other words, the high-order bit is unique, and the low-order bit is unique.

Let's look at another one of your examples.

> The identifier immediately following the define is called the macro name.

We can write a #define statement to see this clearly.

`#define MONTH JANUARY`

The macro name is MONTH, and the macro value is JANUARY. The identifier after the #define keyword uniquely identifies the macro name. So it makes sense to use the definite article in this example.

In summary, the definite article can be used to point out that something is specific, particular, or unique. In two of your examples, the definite article is referring to something that is unique.

Comment: "The identifier immediately following the define is called *a* macro name" is also a true statement, no?